# What are couchdb user._id and role field limits?

Tags: couchdb

In CouchDB _users, I'm making user id's and roles with emails in them.

Are you aware of any special CouchDB problems this causes?

I can't find any docs on valid values for these fields.  They appear to be docs, so it seems ok.

```
{
   "_id": "org.couchdb.user:some@email.com",
   "_rev": "1-0bb5ba9dd3e989a28bc8282efaf32aa2",
   "password_scheme": "pbkdf2",
   "iterations": 10,
   "type": "user",
   "name": "some@email.com",
   "roles": [
     "f@soddddddddddddddddddddddddddme@examddddddddddple.com"
   ],
   "derived_key": "f1f41961688ffd35addebdd0ece7714b08242c5e",
   "salt": "3d299831afccb98c39ddeb3308275acb"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CouchDB Core Dev here. There are no semantic limits to either the `_id` field roles.

The only thing is that the `_id` needs to start with `org.couchdb.user:`.

Roles are just arrays of strings, anything that goes into a string can be a role.

General advice is to keep things short, but email-addresses are totally within the realm of applicable values.

Comment: Awesome, I started to think of it as just another document.  Thanks Jan!

Comment: Is there a limit to the maximum number of roles an user can have? Thanks

Comment: There is no limit, but keeping the list short is a good idea, say under 20.